# Why is Story mode not available on MK11

Tags: mortal-kombat-11

I am trying to unlock the character Frost, but when I go to story mode on Mk11 it is blurred out in red.

My question, 1. If I uninstall the game and redownload all the packages will it work?
2. If I do uninstall the game and get it back will I retain my gold, skins and such?

Answer (score 1):

If those options are blurred out in red, it means those features are still installing. Once they are finished installing they will no longer be red and you can access them normally.

Comment: I checked and they seem to be all installed. If I uninstall the game, will it save all my stuff?

Comment: @HarryIguana Yeah, uninstalling the game won't affect your save data. So you should be fine to reinstall it.

Comment: Great!  I'll try that